# error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741805

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, msbuild, visual-c++-2010

I am getting the following compile error when building a C++ application in VS 2010

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(153,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741805.

I know it has something got to do with property settings, but I am not quite sure as to what i should do, Can someone tell me what i should do to remove this error?..Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't suppose you recently removed some removable storage (a USB drive, a phone, whatever) *without* "safely remove..." protocol *first* ? Just curious.

Comment: Not that i know of..:(

Comment: Whatever triggered it, it _is_ a bug in the compiler.  A compiler which exits with a non-zero return code and no error message from the compiler is buggy.

Comment: Convert the status code to hex to get 0xc0000013, STATUS_NO_MEDIA_IN_DEVICE, "There is no disk in the drive".  An environmental problem, a disk device is misbehaving on your machine.  Hard to guess at the underlying cause without knowing anything about your machine.  Reboot first, try SysInternals' Process Monitor next.

Answer (score 1):

I have a long experience with finding and reporting compiler bugs.

First, MSBuild leaves some files that includes the actual command line used to invoke CL.exe.  It also sets environment variables, so you might need to look at /v:d output to see the actual steps to reproduce.  Get CL.exe to produce the error without MSBuild.

Then prune things out of the source file until you get a small thing that still frys the compiler.  I delete stuff starting at the bottom.  I remove #include's that are no longer needed; expand out the bottom one that remains and continue.

Save each "save" so you can back out when you kill the error.

Then, log an incident with MS.  Once they get it to the proper department, and then determine that it's a compiler bug, they will refund your incident.  I recall having something like 3 credits with the MSDN subscription; used that to get it rolling.

Comment: i gave up, it was irritating.. instead i created a new solution and added all my files again..it worked fine..:)

Answer (score 1):

You may have had imported property sheets which were not compatible with your current build environment.

Try to open Property Manager and see if any custom property sheets are present.

I just experienced this issue moving from VS2010 to VS2013, where I had some old Windows 8.1 SDK property sheets. Building from the command line caused this error, while building within Visual Studio was fine.

Comment: This is the right answer. Try changing "Platform toolset", the problem fixed.